# Unable to Set Execution Policy for Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, executionpolicy, ask-cli

I have created an Amazon Alexa Skill and I have also added ask-cli support to it. When I was trying to deploy it using ask-cli an error came i.e.

`/bin/sh: 1: hooks/pre_deploy_hook.sh: Permission denied
[Error]: Hook Scripts failed`

Then, I opened **Powershell as administrator** and run the following command:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

After that I successfully deployed the skill from my system. Then I uploaded my project at gitlab and want to deploy it from gitlab CI/CD whenever a commit occurs in master branch. But it's showing the same **hook script** error. Then, I changed my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file for just changing the policy and not deploying the skill. Then again an error occurred.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Now, I want to deploy my skill throught gitlab ci/cd whenever a commit occurs in master branch and for that I need to set Exection Policy to Unrestricted. Please tell me how can do that.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57636647/edit) your question and paste the error message in as formatted TEXT, not as a link to a screenshot.

Comment: AFAIK the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet has not been ported to non-Windows OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the error message is **complaining about a `*.sh` file, implying a *Unix* shell script** (typically, a POSIX-like shell such as `sh` or `bash`), whereas **`Set-ExecutionPolicy` applies exclusively to *PowerShell* scripts (`*.ps1`)** - and isn't supported on Unix-like platforms at all.<sup>[1]</sup>

Specifically, **the `Permission denied` error suggest that script file `hooks/pre_deploy_hook.sh` *isn't executable*** (doesn't have [executable permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix))).

To make it executable (by anyone), run something like:

```
chmod a+x .git/hooks/pre_deploy_hook.sh
```

from your project folder.

---

<sup>[1] On Unix-like platforms, PowerShell's execution policies don't apply: in Windows terms, it's as if the `Bypass` policy were in effect (even though `Get-ExecutionPolicy` reports `Unrestricted`). An attempt to *set* the policy makes `Set-ExecutionPolicy` fail with `Operation is not supported on this platform`, as shown in your screenshot.</sup>